# Python xml string manipulaton - adding tags

Tags: python, xml, django, string, xml-parsing

I am doing a string manipulation for a xml file. I open the file do my manipulations with the strings I received with my query for loop then I save the file. I have to add two brackets such as `<document>` to beginning of xml file and `</document>` to end of file just once. Here is my code below. Any idea ?

```
def xml(request):
    filename = "/usr/..../...."  
    programs = x.objects.all()
    categories = y.objects.all()

    with open(filename,'r+') as f:  

        old = f.read()
        for m,k in itertools.product(categories,programs):
            if k.name_tr == m.name_tr:
                s = old.replace ('titlesss',k.name_tr,1) 
                j= k.introduction_tr
                decoded = BeautifulStoneSoup(j, convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
                x =str(decoded)
                x = unicode(x,"utf-8")
                s = s.replace ("infosss",x,1)
                if  m.id == 310:
                        s = s.replace('idsss',"231",1)
                elif m.id == 308:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"230",1)
                elif m.id == 159:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"203",1)
                elif m.id == 163:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"204",1)
                elif m.id == 280:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"212",1)
                elif m.id == 157:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"202",1)
                elif m.id == 282:
                        s = s.replace ('idsss',"211",1)
                s = smart_str(s)
                w.write(s)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("asd.xml")
```

Comment: It would be better if instead of posting a bunch of code which you clearly aren't satisfied with, you described in English what you intend to accomplish in as much detail as possible. It's very unclear, on reading, what the code given in the question has to do with the described task.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [the etree module](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for xml manipulation. Just have it parse the tree, manipulate it, and write it back to file.